# Ubuntu System Monitor and valgrind to discover memory leaks in C++ applications

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm writing an application in C++ which uses some external open source libraries. I tried to look at the Ubuntu System Monitor to have information about how my process uses resources, and I noticed that resident memory continues to increase to very large values (over 100MiB). This application should run in an embedded device, so I have to be careful.

I started to think there should be a (some) memory leak(s), so I'm using valgrind. Unfortunately it seems valgrind is not reporting significant memory leaks, only some minor issues in the libraries I'm using, nothing more.

So, do I have to conclude that my algorithm really uses that much memory? It seems very strange to me... Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the meaning of the columns of the System Monitor? Can someone clarify the meaning of "Virtual Memory", "Resident Memory", "Writable Memory" and "Memory" in the System Monitor when related to software profiling? Should I expect those values to immediately represent how much memory my process is taking in RAM?

In the past I've used tools that were able to tell me where I was using memory, like Apple Profiling Tools. Is there anything similar I can use in Linux as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another tool you can try is the `/lib/libmemusage.so` library:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libmemusage.so vim 

Memory usage summary: heap total: 4643025, heap peak: 997580, stack peak: 26160
         total calls   total memory   failed calls
 malloc|      42346        4528378              0
realloc|         52           7988              0  (nomove:26, dec:0, free:0)
 calloc|         34         106659              0
   free|      28622        3720100
Histogram for block sizes:
    0-15          14226  33% ==================================================
   16-31           8618  20% ==============================
   32-47           1433   3% =====
   48-63           4174   9% ==============
   64-79           4736  11% ================
   80-95            313  <1% =
...
```

(I quit `vim` immediately after startup.)

Maybe the histogram of block sizes will give you enough information to tell where leaks may be happening.

`valgrind` is very configurable; `--leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes` might be a good starting point, if you haven't tried it yet.

---

> "Virtual Memory", "Resident Memory", "Writable Memory" and "Memory"

*Virtual memory* is the address space that your application has *allocated*. If you run `malloc(1024*1024*100);`, the `malloc(3)` library function will request 100 megabytes of storage from the operating system (or handle it out of the free lists). The 100 megabytes will be allocated with `mmap(..., MAP_ANONYMOUS)`, *which won't actually allocate any memory*. (See the rant at the end of the `malloc(3)` page for details.) The OS will provide memory the first time each page is written.

Virtual memory accounts for all the libraries and executable objects that are mapped into your process, as well as your stack space.

*Resident memory* is the amount of memory that is actually *in RAM*. You might link against the entire 1.5 megabyte C library, but only use the 100k (wild guess) of the library required to support the Standard IO interface. The rest of the library will be [demand paged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) in from disk when it is needed. Or, if your system is under memory pressure and some less-recently-used data is paged out to swap, it will no longer count against *Resident memory*.

*Writable memory* is the amount of address space that your process has allocated with write privileges. (Check the output of `pmap(1)` command: `pmap $$` for the shell, for example, to see which pages are mapped to which files, anonymous space, the stack, and the privileges on those pages.) This is a reasonable indication of how much swap space the program *might* require in a worst-case swapping scenario, when everything must be paged to disk, or how much memory the process is using *for itself*.

Because there are probably 50--100 processes on your system at a time, and almost all of them are linked against the standard C library, all the processes get to *share* the read-only memory mappings for the library. (They also get to share all the copy-on-write *private writable* mappings for any files opened with `mmap(..., MAP_PRIVATE|PROT_WRITE)`, until the process writes to the memory.) The `top(1)` tool will report the amount of memory that *can* be shared among processes in the `SHR` column. (Note that the memory might *not* be shared, but some of it (`libc`) definitely is shared.)

*Memory* is very vague. I don't know what it means.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I have a question regarding resident memory: should I expect it to decrease as soon as it is deallocated (with a delete or a free for instance), or should I expect it to float in some other way? Thanks!

Comment: @Luca, while the resident memory _can_ go down when a process `free()`s its memory, the memory allocator might _not_ give the memory back to the operating system. If you free a large chunk (larger than one page, maybe much larger), then I might expect the usage to go back down again. But if you're freeing objects smaller than one page, even if you free lots of them, I wouldn't always expect the resident set size to decrease.